# Linking a php script to an HTML document

Tags: php, html

I would like to run a php script which is the forr action in an html document. The HTML code i have is as follows

```
<html><head><title>Using PHP</title></head>
<body>
<form action="form.php" method="post">
IP ADDRESS:<input type="text" name="IP"><input type="submit"><form>
</body></html>
```

I am using Ubuntu so i have saved this file to /var/www .
The php script that i have titled form.php, which is also in /var/www is as follows

```
<?php
echo "Todd"
?>
```

When i paste `http://10.0.0.98` into my browser, i get the form and when i click on submit, it downloads something which cannot be opened. I would want to view the script results on the browser. I do not know where i am going wrong, still very much new to PHP.

Comment: What happens if you open your PhP script "manually" ?

Comment: Sounds like your webserver either isn't configured to run PHP scripts, or doesn't default the content type properly.

Comment: [Installing PHP5 on Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/installing-php5-and-apache-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 2):

Be sure if you are using apache2 you have activated `libapache2-mod-php5`

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```